# Why do we store values from s registers to stack rather than moving to a new register in functions?

Tags: stack, mips, cpu-registers

I have learnt that by convention when using 's' registers in functions, they shouldn't be modified and should be stored in stacked. 
Is it wrong to just move the value of the s register to a temporary register and work with it and return it? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not wrong. However, there are some limitations and sometimes you will have to store the register's content in memory.

If your function does not call any other function, then you may save the `s` registers in temporary registers, provided that your routine does not need to use those temporary registers. If you need to use those temporary registers then you will end up using memory to backup original content.

On the other hand, if your routine calls another routine you cannot assume that the temporary registers will be preserved (the convention states that `s` registers are to be preserved). Thus if you call another routine you will probably need to save `s` registers in memory (for example in the stack).